# Porque a variável descrição está saindo null?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, null

Não entendi o porque de a variável `descricao` não estar produzindo os valores. No caso, deveria sair assim:

> Carregador antigo conectando a tomada de conector de dois pinos

Mas está saindo:

> Carregador antigo conectando a tomada de NULL

Segue a classe `TomadaDeDoisPinos`:

```
package Adapter;

public class TomadaDeDoisPinos implements TomadaDeDoisPinosIF{

    @Override 
    public void conectar(ConectorDeDoisPinos conector) {
        System.out.println(conector.getDescricao());  
    } 
}
```

Segue a classe `ConectorDeDoisPinos`:

```
package Adapter;

public class ConectorDeDoisPinos {

    protected String descricao;    

    public String getDescricao(){  
        this.descricao =" conector de dois pinos."; 
        return this.descricao;   
    } 

}
```

Segue a classe `CarregadorAntigo`:

```
package Adapter;

public class CarregadorAntigo extends ConectorDeDoisPinos{


    public String getDescricao(){  
        return "Carregador antigo conectando a tomada de "+descricao;   
    }    
}
```

Segue a interface `TomadaDeDoisPinosIF`:

```
package Adapter;

public interface TomadaDeDoisPinosIF { 

    public void conectar(ConectorDeDoisPinos conector);

}
```

Segue a classe de `Teste`:

```
package Adapter;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConectorDeDoisPinos cAntigo = new CarregadorAntigo();
        TomadaDeDoisPinos tomadaDeDoisPinos = new TomadaDeDoisPinos();

        tomadaDeDoisPinos.conectar(cAntigo);       

    }   
}
```

Comment: Com o código atual não dá para reproduzir o problema. Fiz uma adaptação para compilar a apresenta outro resultado. Dê mais informações para podermos ajudar você. http://ideone.com/mTi9PP

Comment: Coloquei a classe Carregador antigo, que faltava

Comment: Você precisa inicializar o membro, como deseja fazer isto?

Comment: Quero que a variavel descricao da classe ConectorDeDoisPinos seja inicializada no metodo getDescricao dentro da classe que tá, mas ela está nula daquela forma como tá,

Comment: Tome cuidado com heranças de implementação, especialmente quando você sobreescreve código herdado: Esta é uma boa forma de transformaar o seu código em um espaguete infestado de bugs e entupido de gambiarras. O seu código dá a entender que você não entende direito como é que a sobreescrita de métodos funciona e nem quando você deve ou não aplicá-la, então eu recomendo estudar bem este tópico. Ah, e por sinal, alterar campos de objetos dentro de getters é abrir uma caixa de pandora, só vai te dar problemas e dores-de-cabeça.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este código parece estar bem errado. Mas sei lá, pode ser um exercício inicial. De qualquer forma estará aprendendo de um jeito que considero errado.

Para consertar o problema apresentado bastaria inicializar o membro da classe para que ele não fique nulo. O fato de herdar a estrutura de uma classe em outra não significa que vai herdar tudo o que ocorre com ela. Então basta mudar o método da classe que cria o objeto assim:

```
class CarregadorAntigo extends ConectorDeDoisPinos {

    @Override 
    public String getDescricao() {  
        this.descricao =" conector de dois pinos."; 
        return "Carregador antigo conectando a tomada de " + descricao;   
    }    
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HWOJB2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/aymjkzhv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/InitializeObject.java).